# What is keos in regards to cleos and nodeos?

Tags: cleos, nodeos, keosd

I know that cleos is for communicating with nodeos which communicates with the EOS blockchain as a whole.

But what is keos in relation to those 2? Also is keos also packaged with nodeos and cleos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keosd` is the tool that manages the wallet: it stores and encrypts key pairs that `cleos` uses to sign transactions before sending them to `nodeos`.

The image below describes the workflow: user wants to make a transaction, they run a `cleos` command to communicate what transaction they wish to perform; `cleos` packs a properly formatted transaction according to the instructions; it fetches from `keosd` the relevant keys that are required to sign the transaction (e.g. based on `-p` flag); then it dispatches the signed transaction to `nodeos`.

`nodeos` doesn't interact with `keosd`: `nodeos` just expects properly signed transactions that it can verify with the public keys that are already stored in RAM for the relevant authorities.

[image: diagram of tools from developers site]

> Also is keos also packaged with nodeos and cleos?

Yes, but it is planned that in future versions those tools can be downloaded [as independent binaries](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/pull/6003).

Comment: Where is the link to all 3 of these applications?

Comment: what do you mean? they're all packaged in [`eosio` software](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos) and the docs are on [the official developer portal](https://developers.eos.io)